# Обработка изображения 360-веб-камеры в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, web-camera, текстура, vr

В общем-то, проблема кажется не сложной, но я не могу с ней справиться.

Моя 360-камера получает стереоскопическое изображение:
[image: Стерео]
Этот видео-поток надо натянуть на сферу так, чтобы не было искажений и чёрных промежутков, которые есть, например, вот тут:
[image: червяки]
Максимум, что я нашёл, так это вот [этого чела](https://community.theta360.guide/t/simplest-webcam-test-in-unity/516), которому каким-то образом удалось обработать камеру (правда, он использует THETA, а я - Insta360).

Кто может подсказать/помочь хоть чем-нибудь?